# Python: interpolate between more than 2 colors

Tags: python, colors, interpolation

In R, the *colorRampPalette()* function is very handy to interpolate between *n* colors in order to create new color palettes. I'm wondering whether there is a similar function somewhere in the Python packages ?
Best

```
# The R code that I would like to translate
pal = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "yellow", "red"))(10)
plot(1:10, 1:10, col=pal, cex=10, pch=16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am not aware of any direct methode to achive exactly the same result, however since there is no other response let me maybe point out how it is usually done with python if you come from r.

One way to choose a colour range is by picking a pre-made colour map of the matplotlib package. You can view most available colour maps here: https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html.

Another nice function that creates a spectrum of colours depending on how many colours you want is the rainbow function which is used like this:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
NrCol = #Enter formula or methode to calculate total number of colours needed 
colour = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,NrCol))
for j in range(NrCol):
     color = colour[j] #this is the specific colour that you would never stand alone like this but rather use in a plot function
```

Of all the colours you get there, you could pick a certain range of course, but this would be a very rough, hard-coded solution.

Comment: Thanks for that quick reply. It helped me going in the right direction using the cm module from matplotlib. Unfortunately there seems to be no easy solution to enter your own set of colors for interpolation.

Comment: Yes, this is all I know as well unfortunatly. When I started with python I asked myself similar questions but I did not find any answers up to today. I always solved my Problems with the colour maps though. There are so many, there seems to be a fitting one for everyone.I am happy to hear that it helped you and I wish you the best of luck with your code

Comment: Thank you Mr Blue. Good luck too.